# cordova ./create function not found Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, cordova

I'm digging around in PhoneGap to build a quick prototype we need.
When I navigate to the

~/cordova-2.1.0/bin$

and run

./create ~/jdphonegap com.jdphonegap.app JDPhoneGap

I get the following error

unexpected operator
./create: 48: ./create: function: not found

I'm not the only one:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/uI_rmd-Gto0

A little help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change the first line in `create` script from

   `#! /bin/sh`
   to

   `#!/bin/bash`
2. Download `commons-codec-1.6` from main server:
   http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/codec/binaries/commons-codec-1.6-bin.tar.gz
   Extract the `commons-codec-1.6.jar` and place it to the `cordova-android/framework/libs/` (need to create `libs`)
   Alternatively change the URL of this package in `create` script at line 96
3. Install `ant` if you don't have it: http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/ant-current-bin.zip, extract and add the ant `bin` folder in your PATH
   Example for `ant` installed in `/usr/local`:

   export PATH=/usr/local/ant/bin:$PATH

Then you can run the `create` script as documented.

Comment: worked for me. Also using m-project. Also I updated to the new cordova and this issue seems to be fixed

Answer (score 1):

see this line of create script:

```
ANDROID_BIN=$( which android )
```

if the environment variable "android" is not set it does not work.

In my case, I ran the following command:

```
export PATH= android-sdk-linux/tools/:$PATH
```

and with this it worked.

Comment: I came with android not found issue. Solved by setting symbolic link "cd usr/local/bin ; sudo ln -s path/to/android".